# What is the idiomatic way of mapping a single enum variant into a Result in Rust?

Tags: enums, rust

I have an enum type defined as

```
enum MyEnum {
    Foo(SomeType),
    Bar(SomethingElse),
    Baz(YetAnotherThing),
    ...
}
```

And I often need to match on a single case, within the context of a `Result`-returning function. More specifically, I write code like this:

```
impl MyEnum {
    fn as_foo(&self) -> Result<&SomeType, Error> {
        if let MyEnum::Foo(x) = y {
            Ok(&x)
        } else {
            Err(MismatchError)
        }
    }

    fn as_bar(&self) -> Result<&SomethingElse, Error> {
         ...
    }

    ...

}
```

So that later I can do

```
let x = myenum.as_foo()?
```

instead of the more cumbersome

```
if let MyEnum::Foo(x) = myenum {
    ...
} else {
    return Err(MismatchError);
}
```

Surely there is a more efficient way to get that effect than by hand-writing a method for every possible variant ? Is there something in the language already, or should I research writing my own macro ?

It's not clear to me how to handle cases where there is more than one field, or if there are named fields. The former probably through a tuple ? The latter I can always reduce by introducing intermediary structs.

Comment: I wrote a procedural macro to automatically generate these accessors for me (`is_foo`, `as_foo`, `into_foo`), only for the case of a single member variable, but it still generates the same code that you've shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with a simple accessor macro:

```
macro_rules! try_unpack {
    ($variant:path, $value:expr) => {
        if let $variant(x) = $value {
            x
        } else {
            return Err(MismatchError)
        }   
    }
}

struct SomeType;
struct SomethingElse;
struct YetAnotherThing;

enum MyEnum {
    Foo(SomeType),
    Bar(SomethingElse),
    Baz(YetAnotherThing)
}

struct MismatchError;

fn test(x: MyEnum) -> Result<i32, MismatchError> {
    let y: SomethingElse = try_unpack!(MyEnum::Bar, x);
    return 42;
}
```

Comment: I am always uncomfortable with macros hiding control-flow. Why not use the macro to generate the getters instead?